# Loading xgboost model trained in python to scala

Tags: python, scala, scikit-learn, xgboost

I have trained a model using sklearn api and saved the model

```
from xgboost.sklearn import XGBClassifier
model = XGBClassifier()
model.fit(X_train, y_train)
with open(path + '.pkl', 'wb') as file:
    cPickle.dump(model, file)
```

Is there a way to load it with scala API?

If I train it using the python API (not the sklearn API) and save it using the:

```
model.save_model("trained_model.model")
```

then I can load it with scala using:

```
import ml.dmlc.xgboost4j.scala.XGBoost
val model = XGBoost.loadModel("trained_model.model")
```

Is there a similar way for loading a pkl formated model in scala?

Or alternatively is it possible to convert a sklearned-api-xgboost-model to a python-api-model? and after the python-api-model can be loaded using the above code.

Any insights?

Comment: No. While not impossible per se, pickle is designed to be python <-> python.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For those who come up to this question, the solution is:

When you train a model using the sklearn API you can save as:

```
model._Booster.save_model("trained_model.model")
```

`save_model` is used in python API.

Later this model can be loaded in scala API as described in the question:

```
val model = XGBoost.loadModel("trained_model.model")
```

Comment: That's not an answer. You asked about re-using pickle-based serialized data and now answer with: don't use pickle-based serialization but something else (on your own question!). It's also no new information: nothing not already in the question!

Comment: My question is how to re-use a trained model in python to scala with whatever api(python/sklearn) is trained. There is not a question for re-using specifically pickle.

Comment: ```Is there a similar way for loading a pkl formated model in scala?```

Comment: `Or alternatively... `. The main question is loading a model trained in python to scala.